# How to read full length of data from BLE in android when my data contain 0x0a and 0x0d?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am able to connect to the device correctly and it can receive the characteristic correctly without any errors. But it gets something wrong when the received data contain 0x0a and 0x0d.

For example, the device sends the data as **0b710a6000179c21346fb23feec651bc** to the mobile app. The app will receive the message as below. The app split the data into 2 data.

> D/BluetoothLeService: Receive Data = 0B71
>
> D/BluetoothLeService: Receive Data = 6000179C21346FB23FEEC651BC

This is the log message from the function **broadcastUpdate**

```
private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        ...
    } else {
        // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
        final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            String hexData=DeviceControlActivity.bytesToHex(data);
            Log.d(TAG, "Receive Data = "+hexData);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, data);
        }
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

I tried to use nRF Connect application to test the BLE write/read but it also gets the same output as above. Then I found that 0x0A is the newline character `\n` and 0x0D is the return characters `\r`.

Is there any way to receive the full length of data when it contains `0x0A` and `0x0D`? So the app can receive full data as `0B710A6000179C21346FB23FEEC651BC`.
Please advice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

BLE stacks do not analyze the data at all.

It must be the application running on the remote device that splits the data into two parts before sending.

Comment: Emil, thanks for your reply. But other data without 0x0A and 0x0D is working properly. So I think the issue is caused by the handling of the BLE library.

Comment: I would guess your remote device splits the data on newline before it sends it to the Android device.